# Pass a variable from view to controller from form submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, model-view-controller, form-for

I am trying to access a variable sent through a submit form. However it does not appear to be present once the form is submitted.

*see the hidden field on line: 2*

```
<%= form_for @import, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :tree_id, :value => @tree.id %>
  <%= f.label :new_branch_data %>
  <div class="help-text">Locate a file for import. (.xls, .xlsx file type)</div>
  <%= f.file_field :attachment %>
  <%= f.submit "Import", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

After hitting submit the action called in my controller:

```
def index
 @tree = Tree.find(params[:tree_id]) 
 ...
 ...
end
```

Hangs up on `@tree = Tree.find(params[:tree_id])` and returns a

*"ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound" 
at /imports
Couldn't find Tree without an ID*

How can I correct this so that the @tree variable referenced in the form can be passed to the controller?

Comment: You must access that var as `params[:import][:tree_id]` Open your form in a browser, fire up an inspector and look at those fields names. ` <%= f.hidden_field :tree_id, :value => @tree.id %>` will generate an input named 'import[tree_id]'

Comment: my hidden field shows as, <input id="import_tree_id" name="import[tree_id]" type="hidden" value="1">. and params[:import] [:tree_id] returns  #<NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass>

Comment: Then I already answered you in my previous comment. You can access tree_id from params[:import][:tree_id] ` @tree = Tree.find(params[:import][:tree_id]) `. Your form submits to create if @import is not save, or to update if is already save not to index. If you want your form pointing to index you must specify this in your form definition

Comment: after make this change however it is returning, NoMethodError at /imports
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 1):

You can inspect the params that you're getting but I guess you have tree_id on params[:import] so ...

```
def index
  @tree = Tree.find(params[:import][:tree_id]) 
  ...
  ...
end
```

Comment: params[:import] is returning as nil

Comment: so you need to inspect params in you action controller, puts params.inspect on your action controller

Comment: returns "{\"action\"=>\"index\", \"controller\"=>\"imports\"}"

Comment: I suppose you are looking for a wrong place, are you sure that your form send the request to index action?

Comment: actually it appears to be calling the create action which then redirects to the index.

Comment: you need to pass the variable name on your redirect_to imports_path(tree_id: params[:import][:tree_id]), notice: "Data imported successfully." and you can use params[:tree_id] on the index action

Answer (score 0):

I realized I wasn't calling the index action directly.

When looking at my controller I was actually calling the create action which was later redirecting to the index.

```
def create
   @import = Import.new(import_params)

   if @import.save
     redirect_to imports_path, notice: "Data imported successfully."
   else
     render "new"
   end
end
```

I changed the redirect to pass the param,

`redirect_to imports_path(tree_id: params[:import][:tree_id]), notice: "Data imported successfully."`

and then accessed the passed param in the index view by adding

`@tree = Tree.find(params[:tree_id])`

to the top of my index action.